# Filter and sort positive and negative numbers with decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using `angularjs ui-grid` to display the data in tabular form. Data is binding very well in a grid. In a grid, few columns have positive and negative numbers with `angularjs` currency filter applied on it.

Now when I filter rows with it doesn't work as per requirements.

I am using below code:

```
                               cellFilter: 'customCurrencyFormat:"hideZero"',                               
                                filter: {
                                      condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue) {
                                        console.log(':::cellValue:::', cellValue);
                                        searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(/^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/g, '');
                                        console.log(':::searchTerm:::', searchTerm);
                                        var strippedValue = (cellValue + '').replace(/^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/g, '');
                                        console.log(':::strippedValue:::', strippedValue);
                                        return strippedValue.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0;
                                      }
                                    },
                                filterCellFiltered:true,
```

Please find below code of `customCurrencyFormat`:

HelperServices.filter('customCurrencyFormat',function($filter){
    return function(val, cond , decimalPlaces){

```
    if(typeof decimalPlaces =='undefined' || decimalPlaces ==null ){
        decimalPlaces = 2;
    }

    if(val == "0" && cond == "showZero"){
        return ($filter('currency')(val, "", decimalPlaces));
    }else if(val == 0 && cond == "hideZero"){
        return null;
    }else{
        if(val < 0){
            return ($filter('currency')(val, "", decimalPlaces)).replace("(", "-").replace(")", "");
        }else{
            return ($filter('currency')(val, "", decimalPlaces));
        }
    }
}
```

});

Showing blank in place of 0 is as per requirement. With this filters the values are coming if I enter `,` in filter. And even without `,`, it is giving some unexpected results. Numbers with decimal never works with these filters.

User will enter number without `,` in filter input box. If no sign is given, display positive and negative number. If `-` sign is given, only negative number will come.

**Update**
[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aItKADZisXWJfIDdPB9j?p=preview)

Please have a look at screenshots:

[image] [image]
[image]